# View RDP connections and identify what one is using /admin

Tags: powershell, vbscript, windows-server-2008-r2

Ok, I have ran into a bit of a stump... I wanted to find out what session is using the /admin or aka console session on a system. I tried query session and qwinsta but I cannot seem to ID this task. Anyone have any pointers or suggestions on how I would achieve this?

What I ultimately want to do is prevent any rdp sessions that are not /admin connections.

Below are some samples that I have done via command line.

```
PS C:\Users\userid> qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
 console                                     1  Conn
 rdp-tcp#0         userid2                   2  Active  rdpwd
>rdp-tcp#1         userid                  3  Active  rdpwd
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen

PS C:\Users\ userid > query session /mode
SESSIONNAME       STATE   DEVICE    TYPE             BAUD  PARITY  DATA  STOP
 services          Disc                                      none             1
 console           Conn                                     none             1
 rdp-tcp#0         Active            rdpwd                  none             1
>rdp-tcp#1         Active            rdpwd                  none             1
 rdp-tcp           Listen                                   none             1

PS C:\Users\ userid > query session /connect
 SESSIONNAME       STATE   DEVICE    TYPE           CONNECT
 services          Disc                             cts
 console           Conn                             cts
 rdp-tcp#0         Active            rdpwd          cts
>rdp-tcp#1         Active            rdpwd          cts
 rdp-tcp           Listen                           cts

PS C:\Users\ userid >
```

*Note rdp-tcp#1 is currently using the /admin switch in the mstsc session.

*Note ">" indicates the current session I am running the command as

Comment: What is you end goal exactly? Are you just trying to get the ID number associated to the console session? Typically you should show us what you tried to we can help you work out the issues.

Comment: Matt, thank you for replying! My goal is to id if the user is using a standard rdp connection or a rdp console connectoin (computer name /admin).

Comment: I will post what I did and point out where I am stuck. One sec.

Comment: Thanks for the update. No one is using the console session (0) in your examples.

Comment: yes, rdp-tcp#1 is currently connected via the /admin switch

Comment: @Matt - maybe I am approaching this all-together wrong? If you know of any other way to view this information that'd be helpful.

Comment: does this help? `qwinsta | % { if($_.StartsWith(">")){write-host $_}}`

Comment: Hi @Paul - Thank you for the response. However, The ">" indicates which account I am currently logged in as running the commands. Thank you for helping me. It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Matt - That's a great article and thank you for the pointer. However, that's not what I am looking for. that article gets the current users and parses the information for users not a specific remote user type. So, What I ultimately want to do is prevent any rdp sessions that are not /admin connections.

Comment: @Spontaneous1980 Yeah I saw the qwinsta output so I thought that was it. What you are looking for does not appear to be there. Perhaps someone will have an answer for you.

Comment: @Matt - no worries, thank you for helping at least! It's greatly appreciated. This is ticking my brain... (I like it) I am going to try the WMI and see what I come up with. I found this, but it didn't help: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/determines-the-terminal-a0a454a4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the server have the Terminal Services role installed? If not, it doesn't matter whether or not you used the `/admin` switch:

> **Behavior of the /admin switch**
>
> You can start the RDC 6.1 client (mstsc.exe) with the **/admin** switch to remotely administer a Windows Server 2008-based server (with or without Terminal Server installed). However, if you are connecting to remotely administer a Windows Server 2008-based server that does not have the Terminal Server role service installed, you do not have to specify the **/admin** switch. (In this case, the same connection behavior occurs with or without the **/admin** switch.) At any point in time, there can be two active remote administration sessions. To start a remote administration session, you must be a member of the Administrators group on the server to which you are connecting.

[[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/12/17/changes-to-remote-administration-in-windows-server-2008.aspx)]